# Windows XP not able to boot after loading isapnp.sys driver

Tags: windows-xp, boot, chkdsk

When i power on my DELL Latitude E6400 laptop running on Windows XP SP3, i get a black screen and hangs after that.

So I tried to boot through safe mode which hangs after loading the driver isapnp.sys.

Doing a bit of googling i found out [Windows XP not booting up including safe mode](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xprepair/thread/1bb2ac51-8b5c-4058-b835-408524ace776)

So I loaded my XP boot cd and tried Recovery Console.

In the Recovery console, doing 
"dir" gives the error "an error occurred during directory enumeration".

Then i tried chkdsk /p /r which gave **"the volume appears to contain one or more unrecoverable problems"**

How can i fix these please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the harddisk.

Edit: I didn't mean to be rude with the short answer, but in my experience the error message you describe lead to a defect harddisk. So the only option to fix this is to replace the defect part. This doesn't answer the potential other question how you can access the data on the defect harddisk. This is normally be answered by: *We do have a backup, don't we?*

Answer (score 0):

Use a disk scanner from bootable disk to scan your HDD.

If there are errors/bad sectors found, run HDD regenerator (also from DOS-mode). This may allow you to load Windows if it's a HDD problem.

However, that file is a file related to PNP legacy devices, so if the system halts there that may imply that a device in your PC is not functional. It may be a sound card, LAN card or other such devices (even USB connectors from case to MB). It's worth looking into this. Try disconnecting all additional cards from your PC (except video card if you do not have an onboard one) and try to boot the system that way.